# Methods for encoding non-linear probabilities as data

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am working on translating a computing method I developed to model complex non-linear systems with classical computational methods into a form that is natural to quantum computing. The technique involves creating probability filters as data in order to describe the desired solution. Encoding data and program in this manner permits rapidly finding a solution to a complex real-world problem that fits a set of desirable conditions. For example, I have used this methodology to find the most highly probable stock price at a given point in time. Does anyone have any experience they can share in encoding "non-linear probability logic" in quantum computational style? I am having trouble finding examples of this kind of computation method.